# What does the percentage displayed under each PSN username mean?

Tags: achievements, psn

When you compare trophies with someone on PSN, a percentage is displayed under both usernames. What do the percentages mean?

(I'm not talking about percentages on each game.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the percentage of you and your friend's current completion for any given level of the PSN's trophy system. It means you are X% through Level Y. You should see a corresponding bar that acts as a visual indicator of this as well.

It's not horribly useful as a direct comparison stat, as your friend could be 25% of the way through Level 12, while you may be 98% of the way through Level 1. You can pretty much consider it negligible because of that.